# Should I remove the baseboards and trim for built-ins?

Tags: baseboard, built-ins

I'm planning on putting in a built in murphy bed and book shelf along a wall in what is currently a guest room so I can take the space back for an office. I have 6 inch baseboards with quarter round trim at the base along the walls. It would definitely be easier to install the built-ins without the baseboards and in most things I've seen, this is standard practice. The baseboard is just 1x6 molding, nothing fancy and it would be easy enough to notch out and accommodate this. Because a murphy bed is probably not what everyone would want in this room, I may remove it when I leave the house.

Should I leave the baseboards, or take them out? Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the plan is to take it with you, leave the base and make the appropriate notch in the Murphy bed. It should not harm the integrity of the structure of the bed frame. Do what you can to confirm this.